# Connecting to a postgres container from a java app?

Tags: postgresql, docker, wildfly-swarm

I'm in the process of dockerizing an Java app (wildfly server), that needs to connect to a postgres server that's also running as a container.

Now, since the configuration for the postgres connections is in the .jar file, it's supposed to connect to a postgres instance that's running on localhost, when I spin up .jar container it's telling me that it can't find the postgres server (which makes sense since its not running on localhost, its running on a different container).

> 13:00:38,448 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432
>   refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
>   postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Is there a way to override the config files in the .jar by an external configuration file for the wildfly server, so that its not looking for the postgres server on localhost but on the container that's running postgres server?

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: i think [this article](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/07/23/customizing-the-configuration-of-the-wildfly-docker-image/) can help you. Also you can look at [official wildfly docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/)

Comment: Though you don't say in the question, from the tag I presume you're using WF Swarm as opposed to just WildFly?

If so, you can externalize project-defaults.yml from inside the jar and pass it on the command line with `-c` option when doing java -jar